# Android DDMS to show unique device numbers

Tags: android, android-studio

Currently my `Android DDMS` window in `Android Studio 0.2.10` will not show unique identifiers for my connected devices.

It would be nice if it shows the id that we see when we use `adb devices`.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

In the picture below, it would be nice if it said the device unique identifier where it says "Samsung GT-N7100" or at least somewhere in that dialog. Instead of just showing 3 devices with the same names.

---

[image]

Comment: Hmm... at the outside modifying DDMS source would not be out of the question, but hopefully there's an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a work around for **rooted** phones for now.

1. You need to modify the `/system/build.prop` file. Change the property `ro.product.model` to whatever you want.
2. Reboot the phone.

Now you should see the new name in your ddms.

Hope this helps someone.

Thanks